# Is there any Fuji X to Nikon F adapter that works with AI-s lenses and doesn't require stop-down metering?

Tags: nikon, manual-focus, lens-adapter, fujifilm, adapter

I am interested in an adapter that would allow me to use my Nikkor AI-s lenses on my Fuji X-series cameras. There are many such adapters, but they all seem to require stop down metering. I don't want to do that. I want something that works the same as mounting an AI-s lens on a recent Nikon pro body.

Is there a better one?

Comment: *" I want something that works the same as mounting an AI-s lens on a recent Nikon pro body.

Is there a better one?"*  Well, there's always a Nikon body...

Comment: As time passes by, I realize more and more that because of being a film photographer I was misled by the analog controls of the Fuji system, when what I really need is a Nikon DSLR for my digital needs...

Comment: i wonder how you arrived to the decision to get Fuji with Nikkor lenses. If you want controls, then great Nikon Df is perfect, apart from price. You can return or sell Fuji if it's not too late

Comment: Using my Nikkor lenses was never part of the plan, I have native Fuji lenses for everything I need. Using Nikkor lenses is just having fun with nice manual focus lenses, since I have them anyway for my Nikon FM3A, FA, F4 and F5.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but on MILCs you typically set aperture on the adapted lens and the camera will meter correctly with whatever automatic settings you use (ISO, shutter speed).  Focus peaking and focus assist magnification should work with the lens already set to the required aperture.

Comment: @StephenG for about 60 years now TTL cameras preview and meter with the lens wide open and only stop down the lens when actually taking the photoraph. This is critically important on SLRs, since you generally want the brightest viewfinder. On MILCs this is not so important as the preview is electronic, but it's still important in low light, or if you use apertures like f/32.

Comment: For both SLRs and MILCs, however, this feature is important when manually focusing. It's much easier to focus accurately when the depth of field is very shallow. Also, if you use automatic exposure, changing the aperture for preview is somewhat feasible, but not if you use any kind of manual exposure or exposure lock. Then just to preview a different aperture, you need to change the exposure. Totally annoying, at least for the way I work.

Comment: As for focus peaking, I find it useful for video and completely useless for stills. I find it far to too loose for critical focusing. I can focus more accurately with focus peaking turned off just by looking at the image As for magnification, that is very useful on a tripod, but I don't find it useful for handheld shooting with telephoto lenses. The image shakes too much. I can achieve better focusing without magnification.

Comment: In any case, I find I can't really achieve critical focus with a handheld MILCs. The EVF resolution is far too low and you don't have split prisms and other optical aids.

Comment: You sound very unhappy with a MILC and frankly, even though an enormous number of people manage fine with the same kit, I suspect you are simply someone not suited to a MILC - you seem almost hostile to using them as intended and, as such, you need to get a DSLR that can do what you want.  If you won't adapt to the camera, you need a camera adapted to you.  Note, however, that hitting f32 and expecting sharp images is usually asking for trouble, as you hit diffraction and usually higher ISO and higher noise reduction and increased likelihood of slow shutter speed even then.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you are looking for is probably "aperture-ring feeler". That's a device, part of F mount, that allows camera to know what is the current aperture of the lens through mechanical coupling of aperture ring and camera:

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any device that allows attaching Nikkor AI-s lens to Fuji X camera, and has an aperture-ring feeler.